# Base64 decode to file groovy

Tags: groovy, base64, decode

Trying to decode base64 and write it to file using groovy

```
File f = new File("c:\\document1.doc")
PrintWriter writer = null           
byte[] b1 = Base64.decodeBase64(info.getdata());
writer = new PrintWriter(f)
writer.print(b1)
writer.close()
```

This creates a byte[] values like [-121,25,-180....] printed to file.
How to get original data into the file.

Comment: Hi, Could you share the encoding and decoding code of a file in groovy?

Answer (score 9):

You could use a binary stream instead of a `Writer`:

```
File f = new File("c:\\document1.doc")
FileOutputStream out = null           
byte[] b1 = Base64.decodeBase64(info.getdata());
out = new FileOutputStream(f)
try {
  out.write(b1)
} finally {
  out.close()
}
```

But far simpler is to use the Groovy JDK extension [`File.setBytes`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#setBytes(byte[])):

```
new File("c:\\document1.doc").bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(info.getdata())
```

Answer (score 5):

From https://gist.github.com/mujahidk/7fdda0c69d11fc3e4a0907ce4ea77537:

```
def text = "Going to convert this to Base64 encoding!"

def encoded = text.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
println encoded

byte[] decoded = encoded.decodeBase64()
println new String(decoded)
```